# Delete user defined commands in GDB

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I have created few hooks and user defined commands in GDB. Now I just want to know How I can remove or change them.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add more info about what you have done/tried.

Comment: There's a [bugreport](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=22467).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to remove them.  That seems like an oversight in the gdb command language.

You can redefine a user-defined command using the `define` command again.  You can make your command a no-op by just defining the command to do nothing.  gdb will ask if you really want to redefine a command:

```
(gdb) define qqq
Type commands for definition of "qqq".
End with a line saying just "end".
>print 23
>end
(gdb) define qqq
Redefine command "qqq"? (y or n) y
Type commands for definition of "qqq".
End with a line saying just "end".
>end
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I got it. We can not delete hooks but overwrite them without any command.